# Updating Reactive state by specific index changes array to object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, store

I have this structure in my state:

```
state
  books {}  <-- object
    book    <-- array
      pages <-- array
```

In my reducer, I'm trying to access the book array by index and replace its pages array with a new one. I'm observing Redux value in my google chrome before and after the value changes. 
It converts the entire array into an object.Before the 'book' array in redux looked like:

```
book: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

and after the change:

```
book: {{0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...}}
```

How do I maintain the original display of my book object in redux?

Here is the code in my reducer:

```
export interface MyState {
  book: BookItem[];
  pages: Pages[];
}

function updatePages(index: number, state: MyState)  {
    // set up my new pages array here into newPages variable
    return {
        ...state,
        book: {
          ...state.book,
          [index]: {
            ...state.book[index],
            pages: newPages as Pages[]
          }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please post an example of your data before and after the change - especially how you want your data to look like after the change. Its not clear how you want your data to look like. Looking at your `reducer` it is obvious why yout get this structure `{{0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and see if it works?

```
function updatePages(index: number, state: MyState)  {
    // set up my new pages array here into newPages variable
    return {
        ...state,
        book: state.book.map(bk => ({
            ...bk,
            pages: newPages as Pages[]
        }))
    };
}
```

## Edit

```
function updatePages(index: number, state: MyState)  {
    // set up my new pages array here into newPages variable
    return {
        ...state,
        book: state.book.map((bk, idx) => ({
            ...bk,
            pages: idx === index ? newPages as Pages[] : bk.pages
        }))
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, but where is the reference to the index I want to change? I don't want to change all items in array

Answer (score 2):

@Gabriel Ferrarini's answer solves your problem, this why I upvoted it. But, as an alternative to mapping, I want to provide a different answer. Since you have a present index there, you can use `Object.assign` to manipulate the `book`'s pages.

```
function updatePages(index: number, state: MyState) {
  // newPages setup...
  return {
    ...state,
    book: Object.assign([], state.book, {
      [index]: { ...state.book[index], pages: newPages as Pages[] }
    })
  };
}
```

We are using `Object.assign` to manipulate an array with its index here. Again, without mutating the original state (using spread syntax) we simply assigning our pages as `newPages` for the `book` item.

Comment: Yes, it does :) You don't see this approach so frequently. Most of the time using `map`, `filter` methods is the way to go. But, if you have an index as you have here without mapping all through the array you can do it like that.